# Angular2 Formbuilder Show submitted data for editing purpose

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-formbuilder

I have a simple form which takes a user input and posts it to database.

The form is as follows

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {HomeComponent} from "../home/HomeComponent";
import {FormBuilder, Validators, ControlGroup} from "angular2/common";


@Component({
    selector: 'profile',
    template: `<h1>Profile Page</h1>
    <form [ngFormModel]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
    <div>
        <label from="name">Name</label>
        <input [ngFormControl]="myForm.controls['name'] "type="text" id="name" #name="ngForm">
        <span class="validator-error" *ngIf="!name.valid"> required</span>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">submit</button>
    </form>

    <a [routerLink]="['../Dashboard']">Back to Dash</a>

    `,
    directives : [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    myForm: ControlGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }


    onSubmit(form){
       console.log(this.myForm);
       //post to rest API
    }

    ngOnInit():any { 
     this.myForm = this.fb.group({
       'name': ['', Validators.required],
     });
    }
}
```

How can I show the submitted data for editing purpose in the same component. 
The idea is to allow the user to edit the data after submission and resubmit if required.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple different steps to this, I think:

1. Populate the form with the existing data
2. Submit to the same record in your backend.

How you populate the form will depend on how your component is loaded.  If you're loading it with a router, I'd recommend using a record id to fetch the data, populate the form, and then you're off to the races:

```
routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment) {
  let id = curr.getParam('id');
  this.data = this.someDataService.get(id); // return null if id isn't found

  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    'name': [this.data['name'] || '', Validators.required],
  });
}
```

From there, the convention is that you would submit the edits using an HTTP PUT request, since updates to an existing record should be idempotent (creating new records should be POST).

```
onSubmit(form) {
  if( this.data ) {
    // this is an edit, so submit with PUT by id
  } else {
    // didn't have initial data, so create a new record with POST
  }
}
```

If you're not loading the component via a route, then you need something to pass the existing data to it.  You could either use a service or an @Input() field.

If you just want the user to be able to edit their data directly after submitting, then you don't really have to do anything special.  Your submit method can leave the data in the form after sending it to the backend.  You would just need your backend to send the record's id in its response to the initial POST, then something to make your submit method send a PUT request by that id on subsequent submits.

There's definitely more than one way to skin this cat, but hopefully that gives you some ideas.